# I want to get elements from a specific arraylist depending on the selected value from spinner

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

I have created multiple arraylists and i want to create a function that displays the items from the arraylist depending on what was selected from the spinner.

Some arraylists i created

```
    ArrayList<String> delhi = new ArrayList<String>();
    delhi.add("Virgin Atlantic – London Heathrow");
    delhi.add("British Airways – London Heathrow");

    ArrayList<String> hongkong = new ArrayList<String>();
    hongkong.add("Virgin Atlantic – London Heathrow");
    hongkong.add("British Airways – London Heathrow");

    ArrayList<String> shanghai = new ArrayList<String>();
    shanghai.add("Virgin Atlantic – London Heathrow");
    shanghai.add("British Airways – London Heathrow");

    ArrayList<String> johannesburg = new ArrayList<String>();
    johannesburg.add("Virgin Atlantic – London Heathrow");
    johannesburg.add("British Airways – London Heathrow");
```

Some values in the spinner i created

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Delhi");
    list.add("Hong Kong");
    list.add("Shargai");
    list.add("Johannesburg");
    list.add("Lagos");
    list.add("Antigua");
    list.add("Barbados");
    list.add("Grenada");
    list.add("Havana");
    list.add("Jamaica");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function when spiner value change try add listener to spinner in onCreate method:

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int myPosition, long myID) {

            String country = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            switch (country){
                case "Delhi":
               //do something
                    break;
                case "Hongkong":
              //do something
                    break;
             // etc,etc,etc
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a switch-case:

```
switch(value) {
case "Delhi":
 //Do something
break;
case "Hong Kong":
//Do something
break;
}
```

Comment: and on value i should add my spinner?

Comment: The string of the selected item, if you put this code inside a listener, then so think you should be able to do this with list.get(position).

Comment: Check Dev_Abraham's answer, he uses the switch case and gets the value from the spinner.